# Bar Button Doesn't Appear in PageViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller

I'm learning Swift. I tried adding a button in the `UIPageViewController` but it didn't show when I run the application. It showed the default back button instead. I tried adding it to a `UIViewController` and it worked. I already added a `navigational bar` before inserting the `BarButtonItem` but it still won't show. Why is it? How do I add the button into the navigation bar of the `UIPageViewController`?

**Expected Navigation Menu**  **Actual Navigation Menu**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are pushing to pageviewcontroller then try this :-

```
 let myAttribute2 = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white 
 ,NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: kFontname, size: 20.0)]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = myAttribute2
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = kNavigationColor
    let img = UIImage(named: "menu-icon")
    let menuBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.menuAction))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuBtn
```